# C++: Segmentation fault while accessing a constant vector of vectors returned by another method

Tags: c++, vector

My aim is to populate a *constant* vector of vectors from an input stream.
I am able to do so and also print the constructed vector using the `readVector()` method as shown below.

But when I try to access a particular value using the `at()` routine of the `std::vector` it produces the error *out of bounds*. I am not even able to access the [0, 0] element of the 2d vector although I am able to print the whole vector.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

inline const int myread() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    return n;
}

const vector< vector <int> > readVector (const int &n) {
    int i, j;
    vector< vector <int> > v (n);

    // Populate the vector v.
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const int rs = myread(); // row size

        // construct an internal vector (iv) for a row.
        vector <int> iv(rs);
        for (j = 0; j < rs; j++) {
            cin >> iv[j];
        }

        // Append one row into the vector v.
        v.push_back (iv);
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    const int n = myread();

    // Construct a 2d vector.
    const vector< vector <int> > v (readVector (n));

    // Prints the vector v correctly.
    for (vector <int> k : v) {
        for (int l : k) {
            cout << l << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Produces the out of bounds error shown below
    cout << v.at(0).at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

> A run:
>
> Input: (two rows with elements `1, 5, 4` and `1, 2, 8, 9, 3`, respectively.)

`2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3`

> Output:

`1 5 4 
1 2 8 9 3`

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)`

I am new to `C++`. Please help me.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the line

```
vector< vector <int> > v (n);
```

already creates a vector containing `n` vectors of `int` each having a size of 0. The line

```
v.push_back (iv);
```

pushes your new vector *after* the empty vectors. You should either use an assignment or create an empty vector with

```
vector< vector <int> > v;
```

Just print the vector size

```
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

in each iteration and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this is declaring an array of vector like this :

```
vector< int > v (n);
```

And then store the vector :

```
v[i].push_back (iv);
```

This helpful when you need to access vector by index later on.